# What's the Isp of a model rocket "D-size" engine, compared to the Isp of engines that do reach space?

Tags: engines, specific-impulse

Now that I've learned a bit about real rockets, I wondered how a model rocket D-size engine fits in quantitatively. The Wikipedia article [Model rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_rocket#Performance) lists thrust in Newtons, and Total Impulse in Newton-seconds, but one would need to know the mass of the propellant to calculate mass-specific impulse $I_{SP}$ and that's not listed.

A good, quantitatively reasoned educated guess or a number for a similar propellant type and design would be sufficient.

And of course this kind of engine will probably not get your rocket to the Karman line, but I'm looking for a number *to better understand how rockets that do make it to space compare* to a handy, historical reference point.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you google "specific impulse model rocket engine?" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse#Model_rocketry

Comment: @RussellBorogove I hadn't realized that the needed data was in the $I_{SP}$ article but not the model rocket article. Putting information from both articles together, I was able to make a direct comparison between them and real, space-worthy engines in the [answer below](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22481/12102). Having this in one place now allows me to refer back to this when writing things like [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22472/12102).

Comment: Not only is the specific impulse of typical model rocket engines abysmal, but their mass fraction is also pretty terrible - often less than half the mass of the motor (let alone the rocket) is propellant.  This is due to cost and safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22473/#comment63566_22473) by @RussellBorogove is correct and while the information is not found in Wikipedia's [model rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_rocket#Performance) page, it can be found on the [specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse#Model_rocketry) page, where $I_{SP}$'s for space-worthy rocket engines are also kept.

[image]

So for a D12-3 engine, $I_{SP}$ is about 82 seconds. The "12" in D12-3 [means an average thrust of about 12N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_rocket#Performance), so the total burn time is only about 1.7 seconds. After that, you have to eject the engine or the whole stage and ignite a new one.

You can compare that to the following data in the same article:

[image]

The shuttle-type SRB's have an $I_{SP}$ of about 250 seconds, and a good LOX/LH2 engine can reach 450 seconds. Stages using those tend to be about 90% propellant mass and burn for on the order of 100 or 200 seconds.

This puts a better perspective on the difference between model rocket engines and the real thing, and if one thought it would ever be possible to launch to orbit with D-engines, better think again!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63431/discussion-on-answer-by-uhoh-whats-the-isp-of-a-model-rocket-d-size-engine-c).