# Why were the three 122-cm diameter conductive spheres for charge collection in the Shuttle's Space Experiments with Particle Accelerators black?

Tags: space-shuttle, atmosphere, experiment, plasma, spacecraft-charging

From [this answer to *How did three 1.2 meter spheres and a Xe+ plasma contactor keep the Shuttle “grounded”? What did they look like?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/52316/12102):

> - [STS-45 view of payload bay](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:STS-45_view_of_payload_bay.jpg) with this description (emphasis my own):
>
> > STS-45 payload bay (PLB) configuration onboard Atlantis, Orbiter Vehicle (OV) 104, includes the Shuttle Solar Backscatter Ultraviolet 4 (SSBUV-4) and Atmospheric Laboratory for Applications and Science 1 (ATLAS-1) instruments. The SSBUV get away special (GAS) canisters are mounted on a GAS adapter beam on the starboard PLB sill longeron. THE SSBUV support canister is in the foreground and the SSBUV instrument canister with motorized door assembly (MDA) is next to it. ATLAS-1 equipment includes the igloo (center - decorated with several insignias), **the Space Experiments with Particle Accelerators (SEPAC) spheres**, and additional instruments mounted on unpressurized spacelab pallets. In the background, are the orbital maneuvering system (OMS) pods and vertical tail highlighted against the cloud-covered surface of the Earth.
>
> [image: Image of three black spheres]
>
> [...]
>
> Just adding the great image [found by Organic Marble](https://artsandculture.google.com/asset/sts-45-atlas-1-pallet-and-igloo-power-unit-mating-in-ksc-o-c-bldg/1AFFepyCinwdlA?hl=en):
>
> [image: adding the great image found by Organic Marble]

**Question:** Why were the three 122-cm diameter conductive spheres for charge collection in the Shuttle's Space Experiments with Particle Accelerators black?

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From page 10 of "[Space Experiments with Particle Accelerators (SEPAC): Description of instrumentation](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19880012222)":

> A set of three truncated spherical conductors was selected. The spheres will be mounted with their bases parallel to the X, Y plane. With this mounting arrangement, the 1020 mm diameter spheres will increase the conducting area of the Shuttle by about 8%, and they will present very nearly the same cross-sectional area for most attitudes. **For thermal reasons, the spheres are painted with a special black paint, which is conducting.**

Comment: A wise person once said [The answer is always "thermal control".](https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/161172)

Comment: we have a conundrum in a teacup; [my link](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46616/12102) says 122 cm, yours says 102 cm.

Comment: @PcMan your comment is superfluous because you haven't yet correctly compared the sources. Both sources are reputable, mine is a peer-reviewed article with author affiliations including SWRI, NASA/Marshal, University of Michigan, Lockheed and Princeton University. I've simply alerted to a numerical disparity without bias. I haven't discussed which is more likely to have an error. I've not discussed "trust" or believability of either.

Comment: @PcMan this worked for the [gun power Isp question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54476/12102), let's see if we can get to the bottom of this one as well: [Who's buried in Grant's Tomb? Size of 122 cm conductive spheres charge collection in the Shuttle's Space Experiments with Particle Accelerators?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54495/12102)