# Who's buried in Grant's Tomb? Size of 122 cm conductive spheres charge collection in the Shuttle's Space Experiments with Particle Accelerators?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle, atmosphere, experiment, spacecraft-charging

[Why were the three 122-cm diameter conductive spheres for charge collection in the Shuttle's Space Experiments with Particle Accelerators black?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54491/12102) links to [How did three 1.2 meter spheres and a Xe+ plasma contactor keep the Shuttle "grounded"? What did they look like?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46616/12102) which links to [Space Experiments with Particle Accelerators (SEPAC)](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Space-Experiments-with-Particle-Accelerators-Burch-Roberts/16a8a94bb06ef39b1e5412b4331ef1d183449e9f) (the button labeled `Deepblue.Lib.Umich.Edu` provides an open access downloadable copy of the paper) which includes the following:

> INTRODUCTION
>
> [...]At this energy the perveance-limited electron gun can emit beam currents of up to 1.21 A. The previous flight of SEPAC on Spacelab 1/2/ showed that at these levels special means of neutralizing the Shuttle are necessary; therefore, for ATLAS 1 the SEPAC instrument complement included **three 122-cm diameter conductive spheres** for charge collection and a 1.6 A hollow-cathode Xe+ plasma contactor.

with author affiliation

- Southwest Research Institute, San Antonio, TX
- NASA/Marshall Space FLight Center, Huntsville, AL
- Nichols Research Corporation, Arlington, VA
- ISAS, Tokyo
- The University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI
- Lockheed Palo Alto Research Laboratory, Palo Alto, CA
- Princeton University, Princeton, NJ

However [this answer to *Why were the three 122-cm diameter conductive spheres for charge collection in the Shuttle's Space Experiments with Particle Accelerators black?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/54493/12102) includes:

> From page 10 of "[Space Experiments with Particle Accelerators (SEPAC): Description of instrumentation](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19880012222)":
>
> > [...] With this mounting arrangement, the 1020 mm diameter spheres will increase the conducting area of the Shuttle by about 8%, and they will present very nearly the same cross-sectional area for most attitudes.

Which links to [NASA Technical Memorandum TM-89728 "Space experiments with particle accelerators (SEPAC): Description of instrumentation"](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19880012222) with author affiliation:

- TRW Defense Systems Group Redondo Beach, CA
- NASA Marshall Space Flight Center Huntsville, AL
- Southwest Research Inst. San Antonio, TX
- General Digital Industries, Inc. Huntsville, Ala., United States)

---

I've called the numerical disparity between 122 cm and 102 cm as a [conundrum in a teacup](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/54491/why-were-the-three-122-cm-diameter-conductive-spheres-for-charge-collection-in-t/54493#comment180798_54493) and apparently [I like those](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1836/how-extensively-should-we-interrogate-pursue-post-authors-about-suspected-ulteri#comment6732_2836).

**Question:**  Who's buried in Grant's Tomb?<sup>1</sup> What is the size of the 122 cm conductive spheres charge collection in the Shuttle's Space Experiments with Particle Accelerators?

---

<sup>1</sup>[Why did the phrase, "Who is buried in Grant's Tomb, " become so famous?](https://www.quora.com/Why-did-the-phrase-Who-is-buried-in-Grants-Tomb-become-so-famous) and [Goodbye to Grant](https://www.theatlantic.com/notes/2016/07/grants-tomb/492647/)